# locking between 2 user threads

Tags: multithreading

I have a main thread that creates/destroys objects. Let's name the object 'f'.
Now, every time this object is created it is added to the tailqueue of  another object - say 'mi' . conversely when this object is deleted.
Now, there is another thread that runs every second, that tries to gather say statistics for this object 'f'. So it basically walks through all the max possible instance of 'mi' (say 2048)and then for each such 'mi', it gathers all the 'f' objects attached to it, sends a cmd down to the lower layer which emits some values corresponding to these objects. Now it must update the corresponding 'f' objects with these values.
Now the concern is what IF one of these 'f' objects gets deleted by the main thread while this walk is happening every 1s ? 
Intuitively one would think of having a lock at the 'mi' level that is acquired before beginning the walk and released post the walk /update of all the 'f' objects belonging to a particular instance of 'mi', correct?
But the only hitch with this is that there could be 10,000's and even millions of 'f' objects tied to this instance of 'mi'.
The other requirement being that the main thread performance of creating/destroying these 'f' objects should be high i.e at the rate of atleast 10000 objects per second....
So given that, i'm not sure if it's feasible to have this per 'mi' object lock? Or am i overestimating the side effects of lock contention?
Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now the concern is what IF one of these 'f' objects gets deleted by
>   the main thread while this walk is happening every 1s ?

If an `f` object gets deleted while the other thread is trying to use it, undefined behavior will be invoked and you will probably end up spending some hours debugging your program to try to figure out why it is occasionally crashing.  :)  The trick is to make sure that you never delete any `f` while the other thread might be using it -- typically that would mean that your main thread needs to lock the `mi`'s mutex before removing the `f` from its queue -- once the `f` is no longer in the queue, you can release the mutex before deleting the `f` if you want to, since at that point the other thread will not be able to access the `f` anyway.

> i'm not sure if it's feasible to have this per 'mi' object lock?

It's feasible, as long as you don't mind your main thread occasionally getting held off (i.e. blocked waiting in a `mutex::lock()` method-call) until your other thread finishes iterating through the `mi`'s queue and releases the mutex.  Whether that holdoff-time is acceptable or not will depend on what the latency requirements of your main thread are (e.g. if it's generating a report, then being blocked for some number of milliseconds is no problem; OTOH if it is operating the control surfaces on a rocket in flight, being blocked for any length of time is unacceptable)

> Any other ideas ?

My first idea is to get rid of the second thread entirely -- just have main thread call the statistics-collection function directly once per second, instead.  Then you don't have to worry about mutexes or mutex-contention at all.  This does mean that your main thread won't be able to perform its primary function during the time it is running the statistics-collection function, but at least now its "down time" is predictable rather than being a random function of which `mi` objects the two threads happen to try to lock/access at any given instant.

If that's no good (i.e. you can't tolerate any significant hold-off time whatsoever), another approach would be to use a message-passing paradigm rather than a shared-data paradigm.  That is, instead of allowing both threads direct access the same set of `mi`'s, use a message-queue of some sort so that the main thread can take a `mi` out of service and send it over to the second thread for statistics-gathering purposes.  The second thread would then scan/update it as usual, and when it's done, pass it back (via a second message-queue) to the primary thread, which would put it back into service.  You could periodically do this with various `mi`'s to keep statistics updated on each of them without every requiring shared access to any of them.  (This only works if your main thread can afford to go without access to certain `mi`'s for short periods, though)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply! Yes i absolutely agree (was thinking on the same lines) on the fact that i need to make sure that no 'f' is deleted while the other thread is doing the walk which means the main thread routine that deletes 'f' from it's tailq grabs a mutex/lock while doing so .....That's what i was planning to do, just wasn't sure of the impact on the main thread performance though ...guess will have to try it out and see for myself ..and then based on that ..think of other ideas like you've suggested!

Comment: OK i tried this ...and it worked fine for a while ..until... :) Basically this per-second thread can be scheduled on any CPU /core including the one on which the main thread is/was running..So during one such run, it appears that the mutex lock was acquired in this stats-collection thread and then before it could complete and release the lock, the main thread got scheduled to run and ....as you can imagine ...deadlock!  Hmm , now how does one get out of that situation? :)

Comment: If each thread only holds one mutex at a time, there can be no possibility of deadlock.  Are you sure each thread is always releasing its mutex when it is done with it?

Comment: Well, like i said,,the other thread acquired the mutex, but before it could be done/release it's mutex it got prempted (as it appears) and the main thread started and it tried to acquire the same lock

Comment: When the main thread tries to acquire the lock the other thread already has locked, the main thread will block, thereby freeing up the CPU for the other thread to resume execution.  When the other thread releases the lock, the main thread's `lock()` call will return and the main thread will resume execution.  There should be no chance of a deadlock simply because two threads want to use the same mutex simultaneously, so the real problem must be something else -- if you're not forgetting to release a mutex somewhere, then perhaps you are holding two mutexes at once in the same thread?

Comment: You were spot on there Jeremy ... there was a bug or rather a missing unlock in the other thread ...so it was returning without releasing the mutex in one scenario